# How to get the site url in views custom output

Tags: views, tokens

I want to print the site url in views field with a custom output, I tried [site:url] token, It doesn't work.
I already have entity token and entity_token enabled in my site.
Is there a way to do that with or without tokens?

Comment: Do you need to display url as text or some text as link to site url?

Comment: I need to display links like <a href=site-url/user/uid>node-title</a>, so I need   it as link

Comment: Why can't you simply use "/"? There's also the Views base URL https://www.drupal.org/project/views_base_url  which might fill the bill.

Comment: Hm, and which uid do you want to use? Uid of author of the node?

Comment: @Screenack the path will append to current page so I think it doesn't works. I prefer do that without installing any new module, but If I don't find a solution I'll install it surely.

Comment: From a root-relative perspective, if your site:url is `http://example.com`, then both `http://example.com/user/uid` and `/user/uid` are identical, when served from `http://example.com`.

Comment: @Eugene I have a user entity field in the node, so I'm using the uid of the user in relationship with this node, but I'll need also the site-url in my others views.

Comment: @Screenack if I'm in site/dashbord the path will be site/dashbord/user/uid,  right or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, and they'll resolve. I don't see why they won't.

Comment: It's seems that doesn't works for all cases, for example it redirects me to localhost/user/uid not to localhost/mysite/user/uid, it may work for mysite.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add field handler "custom text" and rewrite result as on the screenshot
[image]

but put there your field name instead of [title].